# TinyMCE paste table from Excel in Firefox

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE text editor and I'm struggling with a weird problem.
When I copy a table from Excel into the editor, the table will converted to an image tag containing data url value like this:

```
<img data-mce-src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA14...">
```

This problem occures when I use FireFox v22.0, I tested it in Google Chrome v28.0.1500.95 m and IE v8.0, no conversion done and everything was OK. Also, copying table from Word made no conversion.

My TinyCME initialization:

```
tinyMCE.init({
            mode : "exact",
            elements : "guide_body",
            theme:"advanced",
            width:400,height:250,
            plugins:"advlink,contextmenu,table,inlinepopups,directionality,paste",
            convert_urls : true,
            relative_urls : false,
            content_css:"/css/htmlEditor.css",
            theme_advanced_buttons1:"undo,redo,link,unlink,|,ltr,rtl,|,bullist,numlist,|,underline,italic,bold ",
            theme_advanced_buttons2:"link,|,tablecontrols",
            theme_advanced_buttons3:"",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location:"top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align:"right",
            theme_advanced_statusbar_location:"bottom",
            theme_advanced_resizing:false,
            theme_advanced_path:false,
            theme_advanced_font_sizes:"10px,12px,14px,16px,24px",
            invalid_elements:"span,font,u"
        });
```

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: I didn't find any problem when testing with Excel 2010 & Firefox 23.0.1. And the initialization options are the same as the demo shown in http://www.tinymce.com/ .

Comment: Thanks, but I'd tried it again and the problem occurred.

Comment: Having a similar issue in google chrome were you able to solve this issue.

Comment: @GurgyWurgy Unfortunately, I can't remind what exactly happened at that time but I think I used CKEditor instead. Sorry I can't help you more :(

Comment: @BabakBehzadi No worries it was 4 years ago thanks anyway :)